# how can I catch characters till | with Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I am using regex in C#

I need to parse a string till it matches |

I tried both but did not work:

```
Regex reg  = new Regex("Screen.*?|");
```

and

```
Regex reg  = new Regex("Screen.[^|]*");
```

the code is working but does not match anything.

how can I do that work??

Comment: I think you should `escape` the pipe

Comment: Can you split the string first on the pipe and then parse the split? I'm thinking of something like "var pieces = fullString.Split(new char[] { '|' })".

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression, when all you need to do is search for the first occurrence of a pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` is a special character in regular expressions; you need to escape it with a backslash.

```
Regex reg  = new Regex(@"Screen.*?\|");
```

Comment: many thanks! I tried espacing without using @ and gave me error :) now you solved my problem out!

Comment: @ValNolav: Yup, if you do it that way, you'll need two backslashes in your string literal. `\\|`.

Answer (score 1):

After testing on nregex I think you need to use

```
Regex reg  = new Regex(@"Screen.*?\|");
```

or

```
Regex reg  = new Regex(@"Screen.[^\|]*");
```

The `|` is a special character which:

> Causes the regex engine to match either the part on the left side, or
>   the part on the right side. Can be strung together into a series of
>   options.

as with any special character if you need to match the character (rather than use it as a special character) in a regex then you need to escape it:

> \ (backslash) followed by any of [\^$.|?*+(){}
>   A backslash escapes
>   special characters to suppress their special meaning.

[A review of the basic syntax in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Answer (score -1):

In regex, the `|` is a special character so you will need to escape it. Try this:

```
Regex reg  = new Regex(@"Screen.*?\|");
```

Comment: '\' is an escape character in C# strings, you either need \\| to escape the '\' for the C# string or to use the @"" string literal syntax.